# Can I use both toggle switch and checkbox in one modal?

Tags: checkboxes, toggle, modal

First of all, I am not a native speaker, I ask for your understanding even if the writing is weird. I'll explain it in as much detail as possible. If you need further explanation, please leave a comment.

[image: a screenshot of modal.]

This is a modal, can change the settings and the status (on/off) of action.

1. Toggle switches at top right changes the status of action immediately. (turn on and off).
2. Under the switch, can change a settings of action and saves with '저장'(is 'save' in Korean).
3. '저장' is not "save all changes and close modal" but "just save the settings you've changed".
4. Modal doesn't have close button with clear expression, only 'X' at the top right corner do the job.

I'm thinking of the following ways to improve.

1. I think checkbox is better than toggle switches in this modal.
2. Move the button 'save' to modal-side, not in content.
3. Change the button's action to "save all changes and quit modal", not just "save changes and leave it alone".

I wonder what other people are thinking. Is it okay to improve this mode the way I think ? Or just leave it as it is? Is there a better opinion?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain what does this modal do? It's hard to tell which design is better unless we know the functionality it provides.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever you want in a modal, but:

> The purpose of modals can be summed up in one word: focus. If you need visitors to focus on something simple, a modal window is one of the most effective means to do so. Users must either close the modal, or complete a specific action within it (e.g., reading a message and clicking “OK”, filling out a form, etc.).

<sub>*Source [What Is a Modal and When Should I Use One?](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/modal-web-design)*</sub>

The more elements used, the greater the inefficiency or uselessness of a modal window. As the previous paragraph says, a modal window is for something specific, if we use a modal window for, as I have counted in the capture, more than **ten different actions**, this is not a modal, it's a web page within another web page. A Christmas tree decorated with Christmas trees.

Instead of questioning what elements are valid or not in a modal window, which of course all are valid, in this case I would question whether a modal window is the right option.